# How to transfer report done on verbtex Android app to pc

Tags: verbtex

I made a report in verbtex editor that resulted in a PDF file. Now I want to paste that to a pc. If it possible can I continue editing on the pc after pasting.

Answer (score 1):

VerbTeX stores the source files of your document in a folder in the filesystem of your Android device. On my device the folder is `/Internal storage/VerbTeX/Local/[name of your document]/document.tex`. You can find the file in you file manager app, see the screenshot below.

If it is not in the same location then you can use the search function of the Android file manager to look for files containing `tex`, this will lead you to the correct location. Note that the screenshot shows a local project, if you select the `Remote project` option in VerbTeX then the folder will be `/VerbTeX/Remote/[...]`.

After you find the location you can share the file in some cloud service (Google Drive, Dropbox) or send an email to yourself from your phone/tablet with the `.tex` file as attachment and open the email on your pc. Alternatively you can connect the device to your pc using a USB cable and directly copy the files from the folder that you found.

When you have the file on your pc you can open it with any LaTeX or text editor, for example TeXstudio, and continue editing there.

Note that the screenshot is in Dutch (the language my phone uses) showing `Internal storage` as `Interne opslag`. Also the file manager shown is the Samsung default app, other brands have different file manager apps - however the procedure is probably very similar.

[image]